# Unable to connect to localhost or local ip but can connect to other servers or websites

Tags: networking, centos, nginx, unix, bind

I have a server with nginx|bind|mysql installed, everything is working fine but I am unable to connect to localhost or any websites hosted on server.

I tried pinging and wget and none of them work and give connection timed out.

The server has Centos installed.

Can some one please help.

netstat -anp gives :

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      522/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:245                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      536/sshd
tcp        0      0 <MYIP>:53               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      408/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      408/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      845/sendmail
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      408/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      786/mysqld
tcp        0      0 <MYIP>:245              <MYIP1>:60660               ESTABLISHED 971/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::245                      :::*                        LISTEN      536/sshd
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:40591      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:25         SYN_SENT    1594/sendmail: ./s6
udp        0      0 <MYIP>:53               0.0.0.0:*                               408/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               408/named
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  11     [ ]         DGRAM                    2267686683 394/rsyslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2267685389 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2267692005 829/saslauthd       /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267685792 125/udevd           @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2267691329 786/mysqld          /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2267692892 863/php-fpm         /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2268728297 1594/sendmail: ./s6
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2268038395 1027/su
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267979481 971/sshd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267979480 973/sshd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267979477 971/sshd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267692917 873/crond
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267692891 863/php-fpm
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267692890 863/php-fpm
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267692154 853/sendmail: Queue
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267692091 845/sendmail
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267692004 829/saslauthd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267689452 543/xinetd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689322 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689321 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689320 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689319 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689318 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689317 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689316 522/nginx
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2267689315 522/nginx
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267687195 408/named
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267685796 125/udevd
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    2267685795 125/udevd
```

Comment: What exactly are you pinging? What are the errors given by the tools? What is your nginx configuration?

Comment: Can't connect to localhost or any websites ... how is 'everything working fine'? What *is* working?

Comment: Basically i run a web server dns server out of this machine and both of them are serving the content properly but if i try to connect to the server internally i am unable to do so.. Say i try to wget my ip the connection times out.
**even i cant ping the ip 127.0.0.1**

Comment: What is the output of `iptables -Lnv` and `netstat -anp` ?

Comment: @krisFR updated the netstat output and iptables output gives iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into your etc/hosts file, and make sure that your local host points to 127.0.01. Also check and make sure that lo0 is configured in the network settings.

Comment: Checked and the localhost is present in hosts files and it points to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Have you looked into the configuration of your lo0 interface? You can change the address of the loop back in Linux easily.

Comment: my Ifconfig dump is 
`venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:590749 (576.9 KiB)  TX bytes:7118430 (6.7 MiB)
`

Comment: `venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:<MYIP>  P-t-P:<MYIP>  Bcast:<MYIP>  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
`